# Accessing part of a URL via JavaScript, but not preceded by question mark

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React web app, where I want to use the query from a URL to search a MongoDB Database, and find an entry by its ID.

I have the following example URL:

```
www.examplewebsite.com/:id
```

In practice, the example URL would look like this in the browser:

```
www.examplewebsite.com/5f8da21ba227e300076c3299
```

Using JavaScript, how would I access the id (5f8da21ba227e300076c3299) from that URL?

I figured I may be able to do something like this...

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString)
// 5f8da21ba227e300076c3299
```

However, since the ID is not preceded by a query question mark, I'm guessing that wouldn't work...

I could use a hacky approach of adding a '?' after the URL perhaps in my Router (this is for a React web app), however not sure that would be consistently the best approach.

Does anyone have any tips?

EDIT: I've added the suggestions below into my serverless function, and tried to log the result. Here's my code:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {

  let urlOne = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
  let urlTwo = window.location.pathname.split('/');


  console.log(urlOne);
  console.log(urlTwo);

};
```

It's returning the following error however when I call the function:

```
2020-10-23T10:23:37.878Z    91f31b36-0986-44a1-a7d1-fbd31e066ea6    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"ReferenceError: window is not defined","reason":{"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"window is not defined","stack":["ReferenceError: window is not defined","    at module.exports (/var/task/api/fetchEditDebt.js:12:16)","    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/task/___now_helpers.js:813:19)","    at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)","    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:790:12)","    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: ReferenceError: window is not defined","    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:327:22)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
```

Comment: If you are using react why are you not using the route parameter instead of using the location API? The answer is to use location.pathname but I'm just curious why not use the Router to extract the ID

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();` is a plain JS way to do it, but as @mylee it's probably to look up the react router way to do it, they give hooks that give access to URL info you can manipulate

Comment: I *think* the answer to this is because I’m using serverless functions with no back-end to connect to (if that makes sense).. So what I mean by this is I’m using a serverless function to query my database, it isn’t directly in the client so I’m struggling to transfer the URL across as I’m not using Express in my serverless function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`window.location.pathname.split('/')`

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working. It's returning 'window' is undefined....